# Don’t Mobile HTML 5 web apps require you to write different layout code for differently-sized devices?

Tags: html, layout, mobile

This may be opinionated or whatever, but I think its a fair question to ask.

So everyone at my job is like onboard with HTML 5 and whatever. I think its good to have this functionality possible in a web browser...

**HOWEVER**

For every different device wouldn't you need to support different versions of your HTML 5 application? Is that so much better than just programming a native application? Is the only benefit in this type of usage the fact that you can create one application with essentially different CSS/JS files?

I don't really understand why you wouldn't need different sizing libraries for, say, a tablet vs. an Android m/h-dpi device vs. an iPhone. They are all different, shouldn't the browsers render differently on those devices as well?

I know HTML 5 apps have features that allow it to act like a native app, but if you would need to resize your app for every device is it normally worth the tradeoff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is so good about Mobile HTML 5?

It's a buzzword. Buzzwords make marketing people happy.

For the rest of this answer I'll assume you mean "What is so good about HTML 5 when it comes to mobile devices?".

> For every different device wouldn't you need to support different versions of your HTML 5 application?

No.

> Is that so much better than just programming a native application?

Even if it was the case, it saves having to port the application to a different programming language and GUI toolkit for each device.

Comment: I really don't understand the sizing. Why wouldn't you need a different size version of your app for a tablet vs. an iPhone? I edited my question to be a little more succinct of my curiosity.

Comment: If you are dealing with radically different screen sizes, then you would need to account for that in a native app as well as a web app. There's nothing lost there in using HTML. For similar sized screens, while you can obsess over precise pixel positioning on a per device basis … you really don't have to.

Answer (score 1):

This is a great overview of why HTML5 is a good thing.

http://hubpages.com/hub/HTML5-is-Here-Now-HTML5-Benefits-for-Users-and-Developers

Comment: There’s some pretty shoddy writing on that page. “It is estimated that about half of all Internet users are already using browsers which are ready for HTML 5. Firefox (version 3.5 and higher), Chrome, Safari and Opera are the most popular of these HTML 5-compatible browsers” — what does that mean? What’s so HTML5-“compatible” about Firefox 3.5? HTML5 was designed, as far as possible, to be backwards-compatible.

Comment: Sure @Paul.  I was responding to the OP's original (now edited) question: *"What is so good about Mobile HTML 5?"* The article explains some of those things: Drawing, Video, Sound, Geolocation, Client-side database, Offline Application Cache etc.

Comment: that it does. I just think that talking about “HTML5 compatibility” up front harms it. Like [Dive into HTML5 says](http://diveintohtml5.org/introduction.html), the first thing you need to know about HTML5 is that it’s not one big thing. I think the Hubpages article (probably accidentally) puts across a different and ultimately confusing view.

Answer (score 1):

HTML’s layout system (which hasn’t changed in HTML5) is designed to work on different screen sizes — e.g. block-level HTML elements, by default:

1. take up 100% of the width available to them
2. are as tall as required to fit in their content — browsers are expected to offer scrolling so that the user can see all of the content

This is why you don't need different sizing libraries to view web pages or run web apps on either different mobile devices, or traditional desktop computers with different monitor resolutions.